# What is this syntax?

Tags: c++, constructor, ctor-initializer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does a colon following a C++ constructor name do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272680/what-does-a-colon-following-a-c-constructor-name-do)

I am finding this syntax strange in C++

```
TagDetails::TagDetails(QWidget *parent) :
QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::TagDetails)
```

This is declaration of constructor in C++... What does the thing after colon stand for, i.e. what does ui(new Ui::TagDetails) mean here? What is the colon for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a [member initialization list](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr388.htm).

`ui(new Ui::TagDetails)` means that the member variable `ui` is initialized with the pointer to newly allocated object of type `Ui::TagDetails`.

Comment: And note that you should use the member initialization list to initialize all attributes and base classes.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Yes, sir! =)

Comment: Just one question. In which reference book did you find this ?

Comment: @chai: Probably in this one: http://www.amazon.co.uk/C-Programming-Language-Special/dp/0201700735

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking at is an initializer list. The `ui` member of the class is being initialized with a value of `new Ui::TagDetails`, where `TagDetails` is defined inside the class or namespace `Ui`.

Answer (score 0):

This is called an initialization list. See [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6) for the pros of initialization lists over assignment.

I'm not familiar with the site, but [this page](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html) seems to explain quite thoroughly how things work.