# Please explain the colon in my structure definition?

Tags: c++, syntax, ctor-initializer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does a colon following a C++ constructor name do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272680/what-does-a-colon-following-a-c-constructor-name-do)

I'm reading a book about CUDA & I'm having trouble reading this C++ syntax. I'm not sure what to search for so that's why I'm posting here.

```
struct cuComplex {
    float   r;
    float   i;
    cuComplex( float a, float b ) : r(a) , i(b)  {}
}
```

What does the `cuComplex` statement do?  Specifically:

```
cuComplex( float a, float b ) : r(a) , i(b)  {}
```

what is this called so I can learn about it?

Comment: If you know C++ that look the same than constructor. I guess it have the same semantic

Comment: I don't know CUDA, so I don't know if this is CUDA syntax, but this is definitely valid C++ syntax anyway :)

Comment: I didn't know what CUDA was before I saw this question (had heard the term, never looked into it), so I answered it in terms of pure C as the question was originally tagged.

Answer (score 6):

This is C++ syntax.

```
cuComplex( float a, float b )
```

is the constructor defined for this struct.

```
: r(a) , i(b)
```

is called member initialization. Here the local members r and i are set to the parameters a and b passed to the constructor.

The rest is an empty function implementation.

Comment: ah i see, so it's the same as doing r = a

Comment: No, it is the same as doing r(a), but in this case the copy constructor will do the same thing as the assignment operator.

Answer (score 1):

That is C++, not C, as C structs cannot contain functions in that manner (they could contain a function pointer, but that is irrelevant to the question).  That is a constructor for the type "cuComplex" that takes two floats.  It initializes the two member variables 'r' and 'r' with the passed in values.

EDIT per comment: The r(a) and i(b) parts are initializing the member variables with the values of the parameters to the constructor.

Comment: i get the first part, but I still don't get the r(a), i(b). can you explain that a little more? Thanks

Comment: Do those exist in C? I was under the impression that only C++ has those.

Comment: No, they don't exist in C.  I missed the "C" tag for about 30 seconds before editing my response :)

Answer (score 1):

`: r(a) , i(b)`  in cuComplex ctor construct memory at allocation with value between parentheses.

```
struct cuComplex {
    const float   r;
    const float   i;
    cuComplex( float a, float b ) : r(a) , i(b)  {} // ok 
}

struct cuComplex {
    const float   r;
    const float   i;
    cuComplex( float a, float b ) {
        r = a;
        i = b;
    } // fail because once allocated, const memory can't be modified
}
```