# Boost Asio example - strange C++ syntax

Tags: c++, constructor, instance-variables, ctor-initializer

I've just been having a look at the boost asio framework and the examples. In the source code for [Daytime.3 - An asynchronous TCP daytime server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3.html), the code defines a constructor for the tcp_server class as follows:

```
tcp_server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service) : acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 50500))
```

I'm confused as to how the constructor is initializing the *acceptor_* instance variable which is defined later on in the private section? I wanted to write equivalent code for this initialization within the body of the constructor (just for learning), but I can't figure out how this ivar is being initialized.

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You are asking about [initialization lists](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=464084), I think.

Comment: @Nemo: This is not an "initialization list". This is a `ctor-initializer`.

Comment: @James: You cannot initialize any class member in the ctor body. All members are already constructed by the time the ctor body runs. You must perform initialization in the `ctor-initializer`.

Comment: @Tomalak:  The [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6) calls them "initialization lists".  Is the FAQ wrong, or do I not understand?

Comment: @Nemo: "Wrong" is admittedly a bit of a stretch (though, strictly speaking, the standard backs me up), but it's highly confusing. Initialization lists are generally considered to be in like `int x[3] = { 0, 1, 2 };` or `std::vector<int> v{0,1,2};`. `ctor-initializer`s are something completely different and, as such, the term "initialization list" is not ideal for them.

Comment: @Tomalak:  If you do a search for "initialization list", you will find that your "generally considered" claim is suspect :-).  Point taken, however.

Comment: @Nemo: Google searching is hardly a good way to determine general consensus among experts. It is, of course, a good way to determine general consensus among every Tom, Dick and Harry who ever picked up a free online "tut" and started writing a broken version of Pong on a Friday night after school.

Comment: Guys, I get the initializer list stuff, but I'm confused by this case. acceptor_ is an object instance, but the instance seems to being constructed somehow within the initializer list (passing in the argumets io_service and a tcp::endpoint instance).

Comment: @James: It is being constructed the same as in any other context.  Just like writing `Foo f(x,y,z)` constructs `f` by calling the `Foo` constructor with `x,y,z` as arguments, your example constructs `acceptor_` by calling the (whatever) constructor with `io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 50500)` as arguments.  (This is why @Tomalak is right, and "ctor-intializer" is a better name for these things.)

Comment: @Nemo... so what is the "whatever" constructor?  Is it a constructor for whatever type `acceptor_` is?

Comment: @Nemo, that's what I assumed was happening. So then I thought that I'd be able to do the same thing within the constructor's body using `acceptor_ = acceptors_class_name(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 50500))`. The problem is this didn't work as there's no constructor of acceptors_class_name that takes these arguments. Any ideas?

Comment: @James: Are you sure that is why it failed, and not because `acceptors_class_name` lacks an assignment operator?  Initialization and assignment are completely different things in C++

Comment: Is there an equivalent piece of code I should be able to write for this (within the body of the constructor) that you would expect to work? If so, could you let me know? Because I think that would really help me understand what's going on. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does a colon following a C++ constructor name do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272680/what-does-a-colon-following-a-c-constructor-name-do)

Comment: @James:  No, there is no equivalent that you can write in the body of a code.  That is what I meant by "initialization and assignment are completely different things".  You can only initialize an object when you construct it.

Comment: Ahh I see! Wow I didn't know this! So how do I know HOW this object is being initialized? (It would be useful to know what ivars in the object are being set to io_service, the tcp::endpoint and 50500). Is there some standard "initialization method" that I could look out for in acceptors_class_name's source? Thanks very much for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uhm.. why shouldn't it be able to do so? The member variables are visible through-out the whole class, no matter where they are defined:

```
class Foo{
public:
  Foo(int i) : _i(i) {}

private:
  int _i;
};
```

If you meant how that while initialization thing works after the colon `:`, search for "initializer list"/"ctor initializer" if you want the standard wording.

---

**Edit**: Consider this class:

```
class Foo{
public:
  Foo(int i, float f) : _i(i), _f(f) {}

private:
  int _i;
  float _f;
};
```

And now consider this function and other class:

```
int random(){
  return 4;
}

class Bar{
public:
  Bar() : _f(random(), 3.14159f) {}

private:
  const Foo _f;
};
```

You can initialize a member in the initializer list however you want, assuming the member has a fitting constructor. Now, for `const` member, you can *only* initialize them that way, because inside the ctor body, it can't be assigned any more. You could only do that with non-const and non-reference variables:

```
class Bar{
public:
  Bar(){
    _f = Foo(random(), 3.14159f); // invoke copy assignment operator
  }

private:
  Foo _f; // non-const
};
```

If this isn't any help, I guess you really don't express what you don't understand.

Comment: I tried looking for an initializer list explanation/ctor initializer that explains what happens for this of initializer but I couldn't. All the explanations I've found apply to the case where you're directly setting on ivar with a value provided.

Comment: @James: This is covered in section `[class.base.init]` of the standard.  Each member (or base) subobject is constructed by passing a list of parameters to its constructor.  I guess usually there's exactly one parameter, but there's nothing special about one parameter, it just happens to be a list of length one.

Comment: Ahh ok. Thanks for the edit - I think the key thing I got from this was what you said about const. Thanks!