# Copy constructor called everytime a default constructor is called?

Tags: c++

I was going through some of the questions on constructor initialization list when I bumped into this.

Consider this:

```
class Student {
    public:
        Student() {
            id = 0;
        }
        Student(int i) {
            id = i;
        }
    private:
        int id;
};
```

Now, check this out:

> By the time you get in the body of the constructor, all fields have already been constructed; if they have default constructors, those were already called. Now, if you assign a value to them in the body of the constructor, you are calling the copy constructor. That is inefficient, because two constructors end up being called instead of one.

Source: [What does a colon following a C++ constructor name do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272680/what-does-a-colon-following-a-c-constructor-name-do)

**So, does it mean that when I call the parameter-less constructor, the copy constructor is also being called?**

Please explain. This is really confusing.

Particularly the meaning of the first line:

> By the time you get in the body of the constructor, all fields have already been constructed

Comment: _"So, does it mean that when I call the parameter-less constructor, the copy constructor is also being called?"_ No. Where does the cite state so?

Comment: This isn't a great example since `int` is a POD and thus isn't "default constructed".

Comment: Please explain what was the intention there. When are two constructors being called instead of one. I'm really confused.

Comment: They are referring to the copy constructor of the members (if they were a class type and not an `int`). But this is actually a mistake because what's called is the assignment operator and not the copy constructor.

Comment: The main problem is that you quoted from an answer that isn't quite right.  First, replace "all fields" with "all member variables".  Second, "if you assign a value to them in the body of the constructor, you are calling the copy constructor" isn't true.  You're actually calling the assignment operator after the default constructor has been called.  There is no case where 2 constructors are called on the same object.  It makes no sense unless one constructor explicitly forwards to another.

Comment: By the way, you could save the code of your default constructor by using default a default values.  You'd need only one ctor here :   `Student(int i=0) : id(i) {  }`

Answer (score 4):

It means that `int id` has already been initialized before you get to the line `id = 0`. Because no explicit initializer has been specified, it has been default initialized. Additionally, because it is an `int`, the initialization rules tell use that it will have some indeterminate value.

In practice, for an `int`, or any type that is extremely cheap to initialize, this doesn't matter too much.

If instead of using an `int` member, we used a class, we could more clearly see what is actually going on behind the scenes:

```
#include <iostream>

class Verbose {
    public:
        Verbose() {
            std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
        }

        Verbose(int) {
            std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
        }

        Verbose(Verbose const &) {
            std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
        }

        Verbose & operator=(Verbose const &) {
            std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
            return *this;
        }

        ~Verbose() {
            std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
        }
};

class Object {
    public:
        Verbose v;

        Object() {
            v = Verbose(3);
        }
};

int main() {
    Object o;
}
```

This code will output:

```
Verbose::Verbose()
Verbose::Verbose(int)
Verbose &Verbose::operator=(const Verbose &)
Verbose::~Verbose()
Verbose::~Verbose()
```

Note that we:

1. We use the default constructor to create `v`.
2. We create a temporary `Verbose(3)`
3. We then use the assignment operator to assign the temporary to the member variable.
4. We then destroy the temporary.
5. When `Object o` goes out of scope, we then destroy the member variable.

Note that we basically constructed `Verbose v` twice! We first used the default constructor, and then we basically rebuilt it using the `operator=` call. If we used an [initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list), we could reduce that down to one call to `Verbose(int)`.

Comment: This is a bad example in the OP since `int id` is not already constructed due to it being a POD type.

Comment: Yes, when we declare an instance of  a class, some space in memory is reserved for the member variables and it will either have garbage value or some specified value during declaration.

Comment: In the stated code, it has not been initialized until the assignment statement.

Comment: @JimBuck: It has been default initialized!

Comment: Ints do not get default initialized. POD types do not get default initialized.

Comment: @JimBuck: The result of default initializing a POD type is that it has an indeterminate value. That does not mean that default initialization hasn't happened. cppreference has some thoughts on this: _Only (possibly cv-qualified) non-POD class types (or arrays thereof) with automatic storage duration were considered to be default-initialized when no initializer is used. Scalars and POD types with dynamic storage duration were considered to be not initialized (since C++11, this situation was reclassified as a form of default initialization_

Comment: Hmm, I have a different definition of default initialization then you do then, but any sane compiler would not touch the memory that `id` lives in unless the programmer explicitly has an assignment statement for it.

Comment: @JimBuck: You have a different definition of "default initialization" than the official C++ Standard.

Comment: "not initialized" is "reclassified as a form of default initialization"? That's quite a bizarre way of stating it, but in any case, that twist of semantics on the part of C++11 is not relevant to the OP's curiosity.

Comment: Well, the rule that (slight paraphrase) "To default-initialize an object of non-class non-array type means no initialization is performed" is present in C++03 as well.  What Bill quoted has to do with dynamic allocation, so it doesn't apply in any way.

Comment: Also, you proved that the copy constructor isn't called at all.  Why does your answer claim that it is?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Thats a good point on the first paragraph. And I'll fix the second note as well. At one point, I was using a operator=() overload instead of the copy constructor.

Comment: @JimBuck: The historical oddity that is "variables, if not initialized at declaration, may be 'initialized' on first assignment" is swept aside in C++ in favour of more sensible semantics. In short, "initialization" here does not mean what _you_ think it means.

Comment: Yes, it apparently means "does nothing". :) But the twist in semantics makes it hard for a newbie to understand what's happening under the hood and whether his code will be performant or not. Even some of the answers, before they were changed, were confused and saying that `id` would be default-constructed to 0, which is 100% false. I blame the semantics for that confusion.

Answer (score 3):

They mean this

```
Student() {
    id = 0;
}
```

Is less efficient than

```
Student() : id(0) {}
```

In this particular example, `id` would be initialized in a single step since the member is just an `int`.

In contrast, the latter method would make a difference if `Student` had more complex members, like perhaps `Backpack` and `Books`. If these classes weren't POD, the first method would take two steps to initialize the member, and the second would only take one step to initialize.

Comment: Well in this particular case, it doesn't matter because int is a primitive.

Comment: Yup, thang nailed it. `int` does not automatically get a 0.

Comment: Yes this example wasn't the best to illustrate the issue. I added a sentence at the end to try to address this.

Comment: If you are going to edit, you should remove the "In the first, ..." sentence since it's not true.

Comment: @JimBuck: It is correct, `id` actually is default initialized in the first case.  Default initialization of a primitive is a no-op.

Comment: @Cyber: I've been taught that whenever we declare an instance of a class (`Eg: Student s1;`), some memory is reserved for the member variables, containing garbage values until we initialize the variables. Now, the sole purpose of the constructor is to initialize those variables CORRECTLY. So, in the first version of the constructor you have mentioned, the garbage value is replaced by '0'. I don't understand how the second version is different to it.

Comment: Like I said in another comment, if a "no-op" is classified as a "default initialization", that's just a bizarre twist of semantics and has nothing to do with the OP's real curiosity.

Comment: @TheVigilante: In the second version, the garbage value never existed.

Comment: I agree with @JimBuck's sentiment (despite the confusing terminology): assigning 0, with nothing happening before that assignment (since default initialization of an int does nothing), is one step, not two. I'd go one step further and say that if your compiler makes `Student() { id = 0; }` less efficient than `Student() : id(0) { }`, you've really got an exceptionally poor compiler. You need some class type with a non-trivial constructor for default initialization to actually do anything.