# What is the " : " (two dots) operator in c++

Tags: c++

I have seen the `:` operator (is this the appropriate term?) used in multiple places in c++ code. Exemple

```
struct { u32 G:1; u8 T;} a;
```

Does it mean initialize `G` ? If so why we don't use the usual `=` operator, or the `()` like in `int a(32)` ;

I'm aware of the `:` when used in constructors is this related ?

Thank you.

Some says it's a possible duplicate to this questions : [What does a colon following a C++ constructor name do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272680/what-does-a-colon-following-a-c-constructor-name-do/1272707#1272707) I guess no because the mentioned questions asks about constructors, here we're not talking about constructors. Maybe number of bits?

Comment: Possible answer can be https://stackoverflow.com/a/1272707/7994074

Comment: TL;DR: The number specifies the amount of bits in a bitfield.

Comment: For the record, that's called a "colon".